# How to load my module's css file after my theme's css file?

Tags: 8, theming

In my theme, I have css files loaded through `mytheme.libraries.yml` and `mytheme.info.yml` file.

In my  module I have added a css file like this

```
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    [
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'stylesheet',
        'media' => 'all',
        'href' => path_to_css_file,
      ],
    ],
    'mymodule_css',
  ];
}
```

But when visit a page, I see the my module's css file is loaded first and then the theme's css files.

I want to load my module's css file at the end of html head or just after my theme's css files.

How will I do that?

Comment: Have you tried defining it as css.theme in the yml file or assigning a weight to it ? see more information about it here https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module (to a search for weight)

Answer (score 1):

You can define the priority for the css to load , Add weight key for the CSS file in the *.libraries.yml , the lesser the weight  the higher the priority.

```
  cuddly-slider:
    version: 1.x
      css:
        theme:
          css/cuddly-slider.css: {weight: -50}
```

Comment: If I do this to my theme's library, it will effect the site. I want to to do something with my module's css file which is not a library.

Comment: Your module's css file should be a library.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add your module's CSS via a `m̀y_module.libraries.yml` instead.

And just for the sake of completeness: You could also implement [hook_library_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_alter/8.2.x) and move your module's library after your theme's library. The already suggested solution using weight is preferable though.

If you need conditional logic for adding the module's CSS, the hook is the way to go.

Comment: It is not a library. It is a custom css file link

Comment: As I already mentioned, I don't think this is a good way to add CSS to your site, because that way your CSS file is not in the library system and thus may not be properly cached and is not available in the mentioned hooks. Further side effects may apply as well.

Comment: @Ahmad If you don't want to use the proper method (attaching the file via a library), you'll likely need to approach this at the theme level anyway. The CSS/JS placeholders are typically placed after the head placeholder variable in html.html.twig files, so you'll need a new html.html.twig which lets your module behave differently to the recommended approach

Comment: @adrum99, @Clive, I have used the `hook_page_bottom` in my module.